# Edit rights on individual row for individual user

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a google sheet where each user has its on info, also their google email. I can set every row to be protected and editable only by the user. I wanted to make a script to make it automatic, that on_open function it would allow only 1 row to be edited for a person. But as I read in docs, a user cannot remove its own rights to edit a range or the whole sheet. Is there in google script something like per session edit rights? Or does it have to be refreshed only by a script triggered by an owner once a month or something?

Comment: This will have to be done by someone who has permanent owner rights to the sheet. Though once set this should stay and you shouldn't have to be run more than once

Comment: Well it was supposed to make it automatic for new users, ok then.